# Can I use merge_tags in the from_name and from_email fields?

Tags: mandrill

Is it possible to customize the from_name and from_email on a per-recipient basis? I tried doing this but doesn't seem to be working:

```
message = {
    'auto_html': False,
    'auto_text': False,
    'bcc_address': None,
    'to': {'email': recipient['email'], 'type': 'to'},
    'from_name': "*|FROM_NAME|*",
    'from_email': "*|FROM_EMAIL|*",
    'subject': '*|SUBJECT|*',
    'text': '*|BODY_TEXT|*',
    'html': '*|BODY_HTML|*',
    'google_analytics_campaign': None,
    'google_analytics_domains': [],
    'headers': {},
    'important': False,
    'inline_css': None,
    'merge': True,
    'global_merge_vars': [],
    'merge_vars': {
            'rcpt': recipient['email'],
            'vars': [
                {'name': 'SUBJECT', 'content': result["subject"]},
                {'name': 'BODY_TEXT', 'content': result["text"]},
                {'name': 'BODY_HTML', 'content': result["html"]},
                {'name': 'FROM_NAME', 'content': result['from']['name']},
                {'name': 'FROM_EMAIL', 'content': result['from']['email']}
            ]
        },
    'preserve_recipients': False,
    'recipient_metadata': [],
    'return_path_domain': None,
    'signing_domain': None,
    'subaccount': "account_id,
    'tags': [],
    'track_clicks': False,
    'track_opens': False,
    'tracking_domain': None,
    'url_strip_qs': None,
    'view_content_link': None,
    'metadata': {}
}
```

This is done in Python and I am making a call to messages.send. I get the error `mandrill.ValidationError: Validation error: {"message":{"from_email":"An email address must contain a single @"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Mandrill Knowledge Base](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582777-Can-I-use-merge-tags-in-my-subject-line-or-other-headers-):

> Currently, merge tags are supported in the from name, subject line, and body of an email only.